# Complexity of symbolic computation of matrix inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, computational-complexity

I am an engineer who is working with some linear equation problems.

In my application, I found out that in having the symbolic form of such matrix inverse actually speed things up (for example ${A^{ - 1}} = \frac{1}{{\det \left( A \right)}}\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
d&{ - b}\\
{ - c}&a
\end{array}} \right]$).  Therefore, it is natural for me to raise the question about the scaling aspect of this approach.

Note that, modern computer algebra system supports symbolic evaluation of matrix inverse and I have very powerful computer.

What would be the complexity of conducting a symbolic evaluation of matrix inverse?

I have been looking for everywhere on the internet and cannot find the answer to this problem. Even worst, I feel that complexity of symbolic computation does not receive adequate attention within the literature.

Thank you for your enthusiasm!

Comment: First of all, it may be faster to use a “solve” call in your linear algebra package than an “inverse” call. Otherwise you probably know how the symbolic inverse looks like. If not, see [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix]). Each  of the $n^2$ entries is a determinant of an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix (up to a common factor). I would expect that computing all these determinants quickly outweighs the original computation of the inverse. But don’t take my word for it, just benchmark it.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation but I really need to hard code the closeform of these inverses into the hardware due to some limitations.